How do I get the data for both my hibernate object and its referenced objects if the referenced table has many entries?
I'm not as experienced with tables, and hibernate best practices. If I have two tables
Books and Authors, but there's millions of entries for both Books and Authors, if I want to read/retrieve all Books, I know I should run the query for that in batches, something like
        int offset = 0;
        while (true) {
            Query<Book> query = session.createQuery("FROM Book", Book.class);
            query.setFirstResult(offset);
            query.setMaxResults(BATCH_SIZE);
            List<Book> books = query.list();

            if (books.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            // Process the batch of books
            processBatch(books);
            // Clear the session to free up memory
            session.clear();
            offset += BATCH_SIZE;
        }

However, if the Books table references the Authors table, and for ORM in my java code, I put a Many to one relationship for many books to belong to one author. If I need to read the Author table columns such as "email" for each book, how can I best efficiently get this information if the Authors table also has millions of entries? I'm not sure I can do batching for it.
I know with HQL, I can do session.createQuery("from Book bk left join fetch bk.author"), but I think even if I batch the Book query, since Authors is so long, it also causes that memory issue for Hibernate.
If I do a native query session.createSQLQuery('select * from books left join authors on books.author_id = authors.id') then I think it's fast if the Books table is actually small, like 10k entries, but authors is very big like more than a million. Is it an issue though that doing a native query like this means I would lose that ORM feature, since I have to specify which columns to select, instead of mapping to java objects automatically?
Should I do the top answer from the user Chris I've seen on this post: How do I retrieve only the ID instead of the Entity of an association??
Chris's answer applied here might look something like
@Column(name="author_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
public Long authorId;
@ManyToOne
public Author author;

so I have the author entity object and also just the author id number field, so I can read the author ids of each book, and maybe do a separate query for the Authors with batching?
like
session.createQuery("from Book") // no more "left join fetch bk.author"
//but do that above with batching and put each results into a list of Book objects
List<Long> authorIds = new ArrayList<>();
for(Book book : booksList) {
    authorIds.add( book.getAuthorId() ) 
    // now this above isn't going to be another hibernate query
    //compared to if I did book.getAuthor().getId() ?
}

session.createQuery("from Authors where id in (<authorIds>)"); // and do this kind of query but with batching? 

Is the above the best approach to still have the object related mapping for related tables that need info to be fetched from both, but have many entries, or is there something better?
Btw on the SQL side, the Authors and Books have the foreign key mappings, like in the
Create table Books (
...
author_id int NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES authors(id)
);
